# Passing Variables to Functions in Python - TypeError: Missing Required Positional Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have read other posts about the topic, but none have seemed to work for me. I'm getting an error:

**TypeError: calcs() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'hrs', 'mins', and 'secs'**

When I try to pass these three variables into **calcs():**

The purpose of the code is to see at what degrees are each of the hands on the clock at (relative to 12:00:00).

```
 def input_io():
    input_time = input("Please enter the time following the HH:MM:SS format - be sure to include all colons and zeros needed. (e.g. 3:45:22 should be input as 03:45:22).")

    bool_okinput = False
    while bool_okinput != True:
        if ':' not in input_time:
            input_time = input("Missing Colon - Please check the format (HH:MM:SS) and re-enter the time.")
        elif len(input_time) != 8:
            input_time = input("Too Many/Too Few Characters - Please check the format (HH:MM:SS) and re-enter the time.")
        else:
            while bool_okinput != True:

                input_time = input_time.split(":")
                hrs = int(input_time[0])
                mins = int(input_time[1])
                secs = int(input_time[2])

                if hrs > 12:
                    input_time = input(
                        "Hours is greater than 12 - Please check the format (HH:MM:SS) and re-enter the time.")
                elif mins > 59:
                    input_time = input(
                        "Minutes is greater than 59 - Please check the format (HH:MM:SS) and re-enter the time.")
                elif secs > 59:
                    input_time = input(
                        "Seconds is greater than 59 - Please check the format (HH:MM:SS) and re-enter the time.")
                else:
                    bool_okinput = True
    return [hrs, mins, secs]

inputs = input_io()
hrs = inputs[0]
mins = inputs[1]
secs = inputs[2]

def calcs(hrs, mins, secs):

    degree_mult = 360/60
    hrs_degree_mult = 360/12

    if hrs == 12:
        hrs = 1

    degrees_secs = (secs * degree_mult)
    degrees_mins = (mins * degree_mult)+(degrees_secs / 60)
    degrees_hrs = (hrs * hrs_degree_mult)+(degrees_mins / 60)+(degrees_secs / (60^2))

    return [degrees_hrs, degrees_mins, degrees_secs]

degrees = calcs()
degrees_hrs = degrees[0]
degrees_mins = degrees[1]
degrees_secs = degrees[2]

print(f"When the Time is: {hrs}:{mins}:{secs}")
print(f"Hour Hand Degrees: {degrees_hrs}")
print(f"Minute Hand Degrees: {degrees_mins}")
print(f"Second Hand Degrees: {degrees_secs}")
```

Comment: As the error says, you said that `calcs` takes three parameters (`def calcs(hrs, mins, secs):`), but you didn't pass any (`degrees = calcs()`). What are you wanting the `hrs`, `secs` and `mins` values to be?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I would like `hrs`, `mins`, and `secs` to be what the user inputs. They are to be used to calculate the `return [degrees_hrs, degrees_mins, degrees_secs]`

Comment: Then you need to explicitly pass that information in if you're saying that it has parameters: `calcs(hrs, mins, secs)`.

Comment: Isn't that what `def calcs(hrs, mins, secs):` does?

Comment: @Carcigenicate I understand now! Thank you!

Comment: `def calcs(hrs, mins, secs):` says "I'm creating a function called `calcs` that expects to be given three pieces of data when called: `hrs`, `mins` and `secs`". You need to supply that information when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

The function signature

```py
def calcs(hrs, mins, secs):
```

"asks" it is sent 3 arguments when it is called.
The line

```py
degrees = calcs()
```

calls said function `calcs` but does not send it any arguments (empty parenthesis). You'd want to send the calculated variables, in the subsequent lines, to the function upon call.

Without giving it all away, here's a hint:

```py
degrees = calcs(already_calculated_1, already_calculated_2, already_calculated_3)
```

Answer (score 0):

`calcs` defined to receive 3 params but you invoke it without any paramater here: `degrees = calcs()`

Comment: Ah, I see now. Thank you.